# How to move js file out of a template when it uses template's and django's variables?

Tags: django, django-templates

Most of SO examples of using django's variables in JS have JS inside HTML.
I tried to place JS in a separate file but it stopped working. When I use JS inside template

```
{% url "distributors:search_dist" %}
```

works just fine and it moves me to `distributors/search_dist`, but when I try with separate JS file it moves me to `%7B%%20url%20%22distributors:search_dist%22%20%%7D`.

What are the ways to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set up an application-wide object in my base template that you can extend in other templates if you need:

```
# base.html (upper-most HTML template)

. . .
    <script>
        var myApp = {
                staticUrl: '{{ STATIC_URL }}',
                distributorsSearchDistUrl: '{% url "distributors:search_dist" %}'
            }
    </script>
</body>
```

Which you can then access in other templates, provided they extend `base.html` or are included in a template that extends `base.html`. From there you can access the variables in JavaScript that might be included:

```
# some_page.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block js %}
    <script src="extra.js"></script>
{% endblock %}


# extra.js

'use strict';

console.log(myApp.staticUrl);
```

You can always extend this object in a template with additional values that might be view-specific:

```
# another-template.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <script>
        myApp['someValue'] = '{{ variableFromTheView }}';
    </script>

    <script src="extra.js"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

Comment: And what to do if a url requires  an agrument? It can't reverse one.

Comment: Sure it can. It just depends on how the argument is exposed. If it's something site-wide, like say, a logged in user's id, it's already part of the template context. If it's something view-specific, the object can always be extended on the template for the view, which subsequent JavaScript includes would pick up.

Comment: I've added an example of how to extend the object in a subsequent template.

Answer (score 1):

js will cannot evaluate `{% url "distributors:search_dist" %}`. It is not aimed to arrive on client side. It is aimed to be evaluated on server side by django.

What you can do is to put `{% url "distributors:search_dist" %}` in the html with :

```
<script>
   var url = {% url "distributors:search_dist" %};
</script>
```

the var `url` will be visible by the js

Answer (score 1):

You can set global JS variables in you templates.

```
<script>
    var URL = {% url "distributors:search_dist" %};
</script>
```

Now load your JS file **after** your globals.

```
<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```